# Python in Windows: large number of inserts using pyodbc causes memory leak

Tags: python, memory-leaks, pyodbc

I am trying to populate a MS SQL 2005 database using python on windows.  I am inserting millions of rows, and by 7 million I am using almost a gigabyte of memory.  The test below eats up 4 megs of RAM for each 100k rows inserted:

```
import pyodbc
connection=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=x;DATABASE=x;UID=x;PWD=x')
cursor=connection.cursor()
connection.autocommit=True
while 1:
    cursor.execute("insert into x (a,b,c,d, e,f) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",1,2,3,4,5,6)
mdbconn.close()
```

Hack solution: I ended up spawning a new process using the multiprocessing module to return memory.  Still confused about why inserting rows in this way consumes so much memory.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried manually committing the transactions? It looks a bit like none of this is being committed to the db.

Comment: Thanks. Setting connection.autocommit=False and doing a manual commit with connection.commit() has no effect on memory usage.

Comment: was this ever solved? I'm getting the same problem

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, and it looks like a pyodbc issue with parameterized inserts: http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=145

Temporarily switching to a static insert with the VALUES clause populated eliminates the leak, until I try a build from the current source.

Comment: This solved it.  Wish I had 15 points so I could vote this up.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: It appears the latest code resolves the issue without a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Even I had faced the same problem.

I had to read more than 50 XML files each about  300 MB and load them into SQL Server 2005.

I tried the following :

Using the same cursor by dereferencing.

Closing /opening the connection

Setting the connection to None.

Finally ended up bootstrapping each XML file load using Process module.

Now I have replaced the process using IronPython - System.Data.SqlClient.

This give a better performance and also better interface.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe close & re-open the connection every million rows or so?

Sure it doesn't solve anything, but if you only have to do this once you could get on with life!

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried connection.close() and connection=pyodbc.connect() every 10,000 inserts.  It looks like memory usage goes up if anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a separate cursor for each insert. Reuse the cursor variable each time through the loop to implicitly dereference the previous cursor. Add a connection.commit after each insert.

You may only need something as simple as a time.sleep(0) at the bottom of each loop to allow the garbage collector to run.

Comment: Thanks, freegnu.  Creating a separate cursor doesn't have any effect.  I tried time.sleep(1) after each 1000 inserts, and that didn't any have any effect either -- same for time.sleep(0) after each one.

Comment: I use pymssql for development and don't see half the problems and limitations I see when using mx.odbc.windows in production. I'm guessing pyodbc is problematic as well. You might want to give pymssql a try.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try forcing a garbage collection every once in a while with `gc.collect()` after importing the `gc` module.

Another option might be to use `cursor.executemany()` and see if that clears up the problem. The nasty thing about `executemany()`, though, is that it takes a sequence rather than an iterator (so you can't pass it a generator). I'd try the garbage collector first.

EDIT: I just tested the code you posted, and I am not seeing the same issue. Are you using an old version of pyodbc?