# SQLAlchemy Misuse Causing Memory Leak?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

My program is sucking up a meg every few seconds. I read that python doesn't see curors in garbage collection, so I have a feeling that I might be doing something wrong with my use of `pydbc` and `sqlalchemy` and maybe not closing something somwhere?

```
#Set up SQL Connection
def connect():
        conn_string = 'DRIVER={FreeTDS};Server=...;Database=...;UID=...;PWD=...'
        return pyodbc.connect(conn_string)

metadata = MetaData()
e = create_engine('mssql://', creator=connect)
c = e.connect()
metadata.bind = c
log_table = Table('Log', metadata, autoload=True)

...
atexit.register(cleanup)
#Core Loop
line_c = 0
inserts = []
insert_size = 2000
while True:
        #line = sys.stdin.readline()
        line = reader.readline()
        line_c +=1
        m = line_regex.match(line)
        if m:  
                fields = m.groupdict()
                ...
                inserts.append(fields)
                if line_c >= insert_size:
                        c.execute(log_table.insert(), inserts)
                        line_c = 0
                        inserts = []
```

Should I maybe move the metadata block or part of it to the insert block and close the connection each insert?

**Edit:**
Q: Does it every stabilize?
[image]

A: Only if you count Linux blowing away the process :-) (Graph does exclude Buffers/Cache from Memory Usage)

Comment: Does it ever stabilize? SQLA does store some references to objects: see the "Is the Session a cache?" section in http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html#frequently-asked-questions . If your memory use eventually levels out, it may just be SQLA storing a bunch of object references for later use.

Comment: @KirkStrauser: Doesn't seem to, see update.

Comment: Does commenting the `c.execute` line fix the problem? I'm betting it will, but wondered if you were certain of it. Does the FreeTDS driver need you to commit() to flush data out of its transaction?

Comment: @KirkStrauser: Commenting it out does stop the memory leak.

Comment: @KrikStrauser: Tried moving the connection steps into the loop and closing after every insert. Also tried setting autocommit to true -- neither helps it seems.

Comment: Ugh. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088931/python-in-windows-large-number-of-inserts-using-pyodbc-causes-memory-leak

Comment: Ouch. Well, at least you have an answer - of sorts. Do you have the option of doing bulk loads from, say, a tab-delimited file? I do that with PostgreSQL when I need to insert a few million records at once.

Comment: @Kirk: Well this is for near realtime shipping of logs into mysql. So my best bet might be to do what I am doing but use the process module to kick off a new process every X lines... that sure is crap though :-P

Answer (score 1):

I would not necessarily blame SQLAlchemy. It could also be a problem of the underlaying driver. In general memory leaks are hard to detect. In any case you should ask on the SQLALchemy mailing list where the core developer Michael Bayer is responding on almost
every question...perhaps a better chance to get real help there...